# Django south cannot see any field in submodule

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have such folder system:

```
project_name:
  plugins
    link
      templates
      cms_plugin.py
      models.py
      view.py
      ....
    gallery
    ...
```

I want to use migration for link module, but when I do:

```
./manage schemamigration --initial plugins.link
```

south creates an empty file `initial.py` (`models.py` is not empty, and `syncdb` works well with it).

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

  def forwards(self, orm):
    pass

  def backwards(self, orm):
    pass

  models = {

 }

 complete_apps = ['link']
```

If I change something in `models.py` - south says:

```
./manage.py schemamigration --auto plugins.link
```

Nothing seems to have changed.

I try to add `app_label = 'cmsplugin'`, and run south with `app_label`:

```
./manage.py schemamigration --initial cmsplugin.link
```

but it give me the same result,

What am I doing wrong? How to create migrations for submodules?

Comment: First of all, your project structure seems to not be standard. Did you modify `sys.path` anywhere? Let us know. Also `view.py` should be probably `views.py` (if you follow Django's naming convention).

Comment: Nope, i did not change sys.path. Whats non standard in such structure ?

Comment: yes file called views.py, i maked  mistake in post.

Comment: Usually under the project you have apps directly (you have `plugins` folder seemingly containing your apps). And usually every app has `__init__.py` in its directory (which allows the parts of it to be imported just as Python modules are). It is hard to say, what is the problem here, but the structure looks like non-standard one. Could you clarify? Maybe you are using some custom project structures, or some less popular base projects (something like Pinax apps, but they have different structure).

Comment: well, i think i better create screenshot for you, here it is http://habrastorage.org/storage2/253/70f/100/25370f100f603132587ade0bba3309e8.png

Comment: Solution:

run  ./manage.py schemamigration --initial link

(without cmsplugin)